# ffmpeg : Video is not start streaming in instance

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have setup the streaming code which use the `ffmpeg`. It works perfectly fine in my local system.

**Version in local**

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
```

**Version in live**

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.6 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (GCC)
```

**GCC versions**

**Local**

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
```

**Live**

```
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
```

**Code which works fine in my local**

```
var args = [
            '-y',
            '-re',
            '-i', `${filePath}`,
            '-listen', '1',
            '-s', '640x480',
            '-codec:a', 'aac -strict experimental',
            '-b:a', '44.1k',
            '-preset', 'superfast',
            '-r', '15',
            '-b:v', '1000k',
            '-tune', 'zerolatency',
            '-c:a', 'aac',
            '-ar', '44100',
            '-c:v', 'libx264',
            '-f', 'flv', streamURL
  ];                     
  let ffmpeg = spawn(`ffmpeg`, args);
  ffmpeg.on('exit', (statusCode) => {
       console.log("statusCode ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ", statusCode);
       if (statusCode === 0) {
             console.log('conversion successful')
       }
   })

   ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
      console.log('err:', new String(err))
   })

   ffmpeg.on('close', function () {
      console.log('finished');
   });
```

**Error :**

```
ffmpeg -re -i '{MyS3URL}' -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://{{instanceIp}}/live/myStream

err: [String: 'ffmpeg version 3.4.6']
err: [String: ' Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers']
err: [String: '\n']
err: [String: '  built with gcc 7 (GCC)\n']
err: [String: '  configuration: \n']
err: [String: '  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100\n']
err: [String: '  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100\n']
err: [String: '  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100\n  libavdevice    
57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100\n  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100\n  
libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100\n  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  
2.  9.100\nUnrecognized option \'tune\'.\nError splitting the argument 
list: Option not found\n']
statusCode :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  1
finished
```

**Note:**
As you can see I have console the URL which I have made dynamic URL.

In addition, I directly got **statusCode = 1**. When I paste the same URL in my local termial and hit the enter then my streaming starts.

So the question is why it is not working in live?

Comment: Looks like your live version does not have libx264 linked. ffmpeg configuration should show --enable-libx264

Comment: So should I need to add this in args's array ?

Comment: You need a binary with libx264. For linux, get one from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: It's a little bit confusing for me. There are many package links are there. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Get the one called ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz

Comment: ok I'm going to get it using wget command and I'll extract it usign tar command.

Comment: @Gyan I have extracted this file in `var/www/html/projectName`.